# PayPal API v2 cancelled order

Tags: c#, paypal

I'm implementing the PayPal API v2 in C# and I've got a problem: **How can I recognize a cancelled order?**

When the user wants to pay something it gets directed to this familiar page:

[image]

There is this small option at the bottom of the page saying "Cancle payment and return to company XX". I want to be able to recognize whether the user has pressed on this.

To do so I send a request to api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/ and check the response's status but it seems like this small button is not recognized. Is there even a state for this? The status enum seems like this option is not part of it? Check the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders). When I send a requests even I have cancelled the payment I keep getting status "CREATED".

Comment: have you tried _asking the paypal support_ for support with the paypal API? if anyone ought to know the answer, it's them.

Comment: That's indeed a good idea :) Just created a support ticket

Answer (score 1):

There is no state for an order being cancelled. If you are redirecting to PayPal and specify a `cancel_url`, the user will return to that on choosing to cancel. The order's state will remain `CREATED`, and can still be used until it expires.

To no longer use it for anything, forget it from your system and refuse to capture it if approved.

Comment: We are indeed using a `cancel_url`. But since we have a native Unity3D app which shows a loading screen until payment is finished or cancled a url is not as practical as a appropiate state...

Comment: That's simply all the link you highlighted in your screenshot is -- a URL that goes back to your site or app. Not sure what Unity3D has to do with anything.